# MySQL JDBC Driver not found errors. In class path, verified

Tags: java, mysql

I can't get the Java MySQL Connector to connect to MySQL for the life of me...  I installed it both via apt-get and downloading the JAR to a "Dependencies" folder inside my Java package I am building.

```
javac -cp ./Dependencies/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar:/usr/share/java/* -source 1.8 -target 1.8 -d . SDUtils/*.java
added manifest
adding: Build.sh(in = 158) (out= 119)(deflated 24%)
adding: Dependencies/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: Dependencies/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar(in = 999018) (out= 950443)(deflated 4%)
adding: Legacy/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: Legacy/SD-Utils.py(in = 3576) (out= 1268)(deflated 64%)
adding: SDUtils/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: SDUtils/dbConnector.java(in = 729) (out= 402)(deflated 44%)
adding: SDUtils/SDUtils.java(in = 4091) (out= 1589)(deflated 61%)
adding: SDUtils/dbConnector.class(in = 1299) (out= 769)(deflated 40%)
adding: SDUtils/SDUtils.class(in = 2574) (out= 1568)(deflated 39%)
```

Result of running SDUtils/dbConnector:

```
Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at SDUtils.dbConnector.main(dbConnector.java:9)
```

Source:

```
package SDUtils;

import java.sql.*;

public class dbConnector {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try { Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Core";
        String uName = "MyUser";
        String uPass = "MyPass";

        System.out.println("Connecting database...");

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, uName, uPass);
            System.out.println("Database connected! (Core)");
        }

        catch (SQLException err) { System.out.println(err.getMessage()); }
        catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

    }

}
```

Result of ps -aux | grep mysql:

```
mysql     2929  0.1  1.8 2310936 602096 ?      Ssl  15:43   0:40 /usr/sbin/mysqld
astump   22480  0.0  0.0  14240   948 pts/3    S+   22:20   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

Comment: did you configure your `build path`? In my sense I think that you only put in inside the package but you didn't build it to the project.

Comment: Yes - even specified the exact relative path to the JAR file.

Comment: What is the runtime classpath?

Comment: Are you building a jar file that contains other jar files? Do you have a special classloader to handle that (because the default one does not understand about a magic `Dependencies/` package)?

Comment: I mean I specified /usr/share/java as a class path as well. mysql-connector as well as tons of other jars are in that folder. Even if my Dependencies/ folder is failing to register properly, why would the connector jar in /usr/share/java fail to hit?

Answer (score 0):

This exception is due to the jar missing in the class path. You need to specify the jar path in the classpath while running the program using "java" command also to resolve this.

Comment: adding SDUtils.jar:/usr/share/java:./Dependencies/ to classpath post build on java command did not resolve the issue

Comment: You cannot add jar files by just giving the directory name. Give the full jar file name (probably `./Dependencies/mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar`)

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured the real problem out. I was using mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar -- I should have been using the one without the -bin in it.